# Setting up requests default configuration for all requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to set up requests default configuration for all requests, so instead of doing:

```
requests.get(url, headers={...}, timeout=..., proxies=...)
```

I just do

```
requests.get(url)
```

I did search about it but didn't find a solution for this, I could just think of extending requests to a class like this:

```
import requests
class CustomRequests:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    
    def __call__(self, requests_object, *args, **kwargs):
        return requests_object(*args, **kwargs, **self.__dict__)
```

And can be used like this:

```
Req = CustomRequests(headers={'foo': 'bar'}, proxies={'http': 'baz'}, timeout=15)

print(Req(requests.get, 'https://github.com').status_code)
```

> 200

This sounds to me like a dirty hack to get around that, or it isn't? any better solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what sessions are for: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just noticed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use sessions, for example you are only making one request, you can use partials

```py
from functools import partial

requests_get = partial(
    requests.get,
    headers=dict(),
    timeout=(0.15, 0.15),
    proxies=[]
)

def some_func(url):
    r = requests_get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()
```